# Calling compact() from php extension to C++

Tags: php, c++, php-extension

Here is my code:

```
  zval compact, compact_params[1], compact_result;
      zval A;
      ZVAL_STRING(&A, "test");
      ZVAL_STRING(&compact, "compact");
      ZVAL_STRING(&compact_params[0], "A");
      call_user_function(EG(function_table), NULL, &compact, &compact_result, 1, compact_params);
```

when I call it from php it says:

**Cannot call compact() dynamically**

I dont have any idea now how to call the compact() from c++. I already called different function successfully but this compact is different.

Answer (score 0):

It appears PHP 7 added dynamic call protection to certain functions. See this [unit test file](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/cdeebfd4afd270a7628344b544356f3d15c50372/Zend/tests/dynamic_call_006.phpt#L9-L10) from the PHP source repository. I'm not sure what the purpose of this is. Your code works in PHP 5 though; I verified it.

As a workaround, you can look at the implementation of the [`compact`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/5aac8fdbfc608841769881a192c50b6ef1a5617b/ext/standard/array.c#L2563-L2594) function and use its underlying utility functions to accomplish the same thing. Look at the implementation of `php_compact_var()`. Since this functionality is statically linked, you'll have to copy the code into your extension.